# How to mmap a file in linux kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, mmap

I try to mmap a file in a linux kernel module. I have tried to use the function `do_mmap_pgoff`. But the address returned is memory virtual address in current process' user space, i.e., below the kernel boundary. Instead, I want to map the file in the kernel space and get the kernel virtual address of the mapped region. Is there any kernel API in Linux support this operation?  Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code that you already have? I am trying to solve the same problem, maybe I can help.